# Does hibernate native query fetch child objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entity class called "Book" and it has an "Author" , which is another entity class, and it is a Many-to-One relationship.
So when I call this native query, does it fetch the Author too? I really don't want to fetch the Author object as I only need to retrieve information about the book, not about the author. (I think it is a time waste to query Author table)

```
Query q = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select * from Book where id =?",Book.class).setParameter(1,bookId);
```

How do I get only the Book object without Author information using native query?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "columnName", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Author author;
```

so this will not load data of author.
whenever you do `getAuthor` in any place then only it will get data otherwise not.
`FetchType.LAZY` tell hibernate not to fetch data when data of Book is fetching.

I suggest that if there's only `1 child entity` then you can use `FetchType.EAGER` but if there's `more than one child entity` then it is not preferable to use `EAGER`. At that time `LAZY` fetch type better to use.

My above code basics of hibernate config for fetch type.

Comment: This does't sound right. Firstly, if it is a OneToMany relationship, then author should be a List or Set. Secondly my case is ManyToOne relationship. In that case, it is always fetch eagerly. Also I do not want to change my entity class just because of this one query. I may need to eager fetch always in other cases. How to you stop eager fetching for OneToOne or ManyToOne in a different question. Just simply adding FetchType.LAZY doesn't work

Comment: Yes right, it should be collection element of entity class. I told in answer as well that for basic idea I have given the example.

Comment: But your example doesn't help me. It is a totally different scenario. My question is about native query, not HQL

Comment: Yes, for special scenario handling as LAZY fetch type, i will post you ASAP. I am on it. Thanks.